# SQL: How to reuse an id in another row of the same table?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I'm sql newbie & work on a receipt database.

```
CREATE TABLE Food(
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
                name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
                entity VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
                alternative_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
                );
```

How can I insert e.g an apple and use the id of banana for the alternative_ID column?

Comment: what is alternative id supposed to be?

Comment: An apple has one id which relates to itself & one id from another food, which can be used as alternative for cooking.

Comment: i recommend you setup a sep table called food_alternative.  There's definitely more than one alternative for a single food and doing a many to many up front is way easier than adding it later

Comment: I would use food (id, name, entity) & food_alternative (id, name, entity, food_id) instead & try "insert into food_alternative (name, entity, food_id) VALUES ('banana', 'kg', (select id from food)) where name='apple';", but this doesn't work (food_id references to food.id).

Comment: food alternative would just have the the two ids in it, mapping back to each individual record.  food_alternative (id, alternative_id) - you would join twice to get the id's info and alternative id's info

Answer (score 2):

You would just insert the value:

```
insert into food (name, entity, alternative_id)
    select 'apple', ?, id
    from food
    where name = 'banana';
```

The `?` is because it is unclear what entity means in this context.